How to Programmatically Open Microsoft Outlook App from Android App on Android 11+
I'm trying to programmatically open the Microsoft Outlook app from my Android application. However, starting from Android 11 (API level 30), I'm running into issues with PackageManager not being able to list other apps as it used to. My goal is to ensure that the Outlook app opens directly, and if it's not installed, guide the user to the Play Store or show a message.
Here's what I've tried so far:
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;

public class OutlookOpener {

    private static final String OUTLOOK_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.microsoft.office.outlook";

    public static void openOutlook(Context context) {
        // Create intent to open Outlook
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox")); 

        intent
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        boolean isOutlookFound = false;

        for (ResolveInfo info : activities) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(OUTLOOK_PACKAGE_NAME)) {
                emailIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                context.startActivity(emailIntent);
                isOutlookFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isOutlookFound) {
            // Outlook is not installed or not set as default, open in the web browser
            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox"));
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Open with"));
        }
    }
}

Questions:

How can I reliably open the Microsoft Outlook app from my Android
application, especially on devices running Android 11 and above?

Are there any best practices or alternative methods for handling
this kind of app interaction given the restrictions on package
visibility in Android 11+?


Thanks to CommonsWare for advice, i have added queries to my manifest and then this package became visible for PackageManager
 <queries>
        <package android:name="com.microsoft.office.outlook" />
 </queries>


What do you have in your <queries> element in your manifest?

i don't know what is   , in manifest , but  i have intend filter :

If you want to use PackageManager for this sort of thing, you need to add a queries element to your manifest.
